# Heroku, problem running django app due to bash: ps:scale: command not found

Tags: python, django, heroku

I just tried for the first time Heroku to deploy to pre-production. After building the app successfully connecting it to GitHub, I got an H14 error when visiting the app. After adding the Procfile + adding `heroku ps:scale web=1`, Checking the logs I get the following(along with an H14 error after)

```
2021-06-13T20:31:48.547165+00:00 heroku[heroku.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-13T20:31:54.889231+00:00 heroku[heroku.1]: Starting process with command `ps:scale web=1`
2021-06-13T20:31:55.562137+00:00 heroku[heroku.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-06-13T20:31:57.440662+00:00 app[heroku.1]: bash: ps:scale: command not found
2021-06-13T20:31:57.518775+00:00 heroku[heroku.1]: Process exited with status 127
2021-06-13T20:31:57.661020+00:00 heroku[heroku.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-06-13T20:31:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-06-13T20:32:06.712436+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET
```

Anyone has a clue on why this might be?

Answer (score 1):

Silly question, got it figured out. I removed `heroku ps:scale web=1`  from the Procfile, then added `web: gunicorn <projectname>.wsgi`.

That worked properly.